# Step-indexing: Where to begin?

Tags: reference-request, pl.programming-languages, program-verification, formal-methods, operational-semantics

I am about to begin a verification project (for MIPS)  with my professor (I am a senior undergraduate) and have been told that the soundness proof for the program logic we need will probably involve step-indexing. I have read the [Very Modal Model](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1200000/1190235/p109-appel.pdf?ip=137.132.3.10&acc=AUTHOR-IZED&CFID=194763560&CFTOKEN=29858435&__acm__=1363863619_b7110046a48ec37b7fe67cba12d248ef) paper by Appel et al. and after a short tutorial by my prof, I think I have a basic understanding of step-indexing. However it has been kind of slow going. Especially when the $\mu$ operator and contravariance come up.

I would like to ask for either the original papers where step-indexing was introduced (from what I understand it traces back to the 50-60s? but am having trouble finding them) or if someone can point out a tutorial, that would also be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amal Ahmed's very readable [thesis dissertation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/research/techreps/TR-713-04) could be a nice start.

Comment: Amal Ahmed also gave lectures on step-indexed logical relations at the Oregon Programming Languages Summer School. The videos are online: http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer12/curriculum.html